# HDMI+Acer Aspire 5536 running xUbuntu = nothing

Tags: xubuntu, ati, xfce, radeon, hdmi

I'm trying to hook up my old laptop to my TV using an HDMI cable but it just won't output anything on the TV or the Display part of Settings. I've tried rebooting it with the cable in and out, tried other cables but still no luck. This is on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
       *-display
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: RS780M [Mobility Radeon HD 3200]
            vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
            physical id: 5
            bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
            version: 00
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
            configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
            resources: irq:18 memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:9000(size=256) memory:cfdf0000-cfdfffff memory:cfe00000-cfefffff
```

Full hardware information here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12775982/

Did `sudo lshw -c video | grep 'configuration'` and it returned with `configuration: driver=radeon latency=0`

Comment: @Fabby Ive added the paste.

Comment: And I don't know anything about ATI graphics.  You should edit your tags...  I'll try to see if I can find anyone knowing anything about Radeon... (and put all that info in your question so the next guy/gal doesn't have to read all the comments...)  **;-)**

Comment: Do you happen to have the proprietary drivers installed?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I'm pretty sure I dont.

Comment: Hey those from the Additional Drivers app. Search it in the Dash.

Comment: I deleted it earlier, there's no additional drivers available.